# formatting date in a morris chart with php mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, morris.js

i am just trying to make my date appear "M d, Y" in my morris chart ... i am getting all of the data over correctly, but i can't seem to format the date how i want ... can anybody help?

here is my code:

```
$get_bar_scores = "SELECT * FROM user_rounds WHERE user_id = '".$row_user['user_id']."'"; 
$run_bar_scores = mysqli_query($con, $get_bar_scores); ?>
<script>
$(function(){

Morris.Line({
element: 'line-score',
data: [
<?php while($row_bar_scores = mysqli_fetch_array($run_bar_scores)) { ?>
{ 
  y: '<?php echo $row_bar_scores['date_played']; ?>', 
  a: '<?php echo $row_bar_scores['total']; ?>', 
},
<?php } ?>],
xkey: 'y',
ykeys: ['a'],
labels: ['Score'],
lineColors:['#16a085','#FF0066']
});

})

</script>
```

like i said, all of the info is appearing correctly, i would just like to have the date to show up cleaner ... i have tried: date("M d, Y", strtotime($row_bar_scores['date_played'])); but to no avail.

any and all help is greatly appreciated!! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should explicitly select your columns...but that's another topic.

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_played,'%M %d %Y') as date_played FROM user_rounds WHERE user_id =...
```

Comment: i know, i know ... it's stupid for me not to ... i typically do, but i'm just trying to make this show up right now ... that fix didn't work, still getting the same format but when i change the morris chart to a bar rather than a line / area and do the date("", strtotime()), it works and doesn't error out ...

Comment: I forgot to add the 'as date_played'